# iOS - Cannot Install Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, code-signing-certificate

I've been around Stack Overflow a lot trying to solve this issue, and it's making very little sense.

I'm trying to publish an app, but I'm getting the error:

[image]

This is utterly confusing, because we have three different certificates for iOS Distribution and I've downloaded all three of them and attempted to add them to Keychain. The Preference->Accounts=>View Details dialog does not show the certificates. It only displays (even after refreshing) an iOS Development and a Mac Development certificate. When I attempt to add an iOS Distribution certificate I get a similar error, despite the fact we have THREE valid iOS Distribution certificates.

I've started from scratch too. I deleted all provisioning profiles related to the app in the Member Center, recreated the app Identifier to make sure it mirrors the Bundle Identifier, and generated a new provisioning profile with the valid certificate and app ID, downloaded and installed it, and I am STILL getting the same error.

I've gone into Build Settings and switched between automatic and assigning specific provisioning profiles.

The biggest issue is that the certificates don't appear in keychain. I double click on them and keychain opens, but nothing happens. I drag them into keychain, and still nothing happens.

Comment: in Keychain Access do you see the Private/Public Key pair, or just the public key ?

Comment: Under "My Certificates", when I click on each of the certificates I see only a private key. Under keys, I see a lot of both but it's hard to tell which one is from which. Should I try deleting all the keys and starting over? Maybe that's where it's getting jammed up?

Comment: When you "start from scratch", ensure you delete all of the related certificates in Keychain Access under the My Certificates category. You must have the private key for your Developer ID on your system in order to sign.

Comment: @Macus Adams I did that, should I also delete all of the keys? Also, am I missing a step in creating the keys?

Comment: As @MarcusAdams said, delete all the keys under that profile from Keychain Access and create new ones. Have ran into same trouble and deleting everything from Keychain and then re-creating worked for me.

Comment: So, I deleted all certificates and keys. Worse than no change. Now in Prefrences->Accounts->View Details, it says I'm missing the private key and I can't download the certs I was able to before.

Comment: The worst part is that this problem is generally for people who change Macs. I have not, this is the only Mac I've ever used for development. I did delete xcode once, I wonder if that caused this?

Comment: If you deleted the certs from the website, then you wouldn't be able to download them and have it say that. You need to clear everything, create a new cert with a certificate signing request.